# Error: reference to ArrayList is ambiguous

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, input

I am at my wits end on what I can only assume is a very simple solution. New to java, trying to create an ArrayList that captures user input, then sums the elements within the ArrayList.

Problem is, I cannot even get to the actual calculation yet because my IDE keeps giving me the following error:

reference to ArrayList is ambiguous
   both classes in java.util.ArrayList in java.util and class X.ArrayList in X 
   match.

I have searched the Google and read the java api for ArrayLists and I just can't figure out why I am getting the error. I am using NetBeans if that helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayList<Integer> {

    public void arrayListSum() {
        ArrayList<Integer> pList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
                pList.add(sc.next());
    }
```

Comment: Look at the name of your class and the error _"reference to ArrayList is ambiguous **both classes in java.util.ArrayList in java.util and class X.ArrayList in X match.**"_

Comment: In `ArrayList<Integer> pList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` which `ArrayList` do you mean? Your class or the imported `java.util.ArrayList`? That's what the compiler complains about.

Comment: Give you class another name

Comment: Don't name your class after an existing class. You must have more imagination than that.

Comment: If you really want to do this, do not import `java.util.ArrayList`; instead, use the fully qualified name every time.

Answer (score 2):

You created a custom `ArrayList` class with a generic type parameter you named `Integer`. That causes the name clash with `java.util.ArrayList`. Just rename your class.

```
public class SomeOtherName {

    public void arrayListSum() {
        ArrayList<Integer> pList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            pList.add(sc.next());
        }
    }
}
```